# ERROR 1064 (42000) - You have an error in you SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mariadb

When executing a SQL script, I meet this error:

**ERROR 1064 (42000) - You have an error in you SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'rows int(12) NOT NULL default '600', timespan int(12) unsigned NOT NULL defaul' at line 7**

The code for the create is:

```
CREATE TABLE rra (
    id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    hash varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    x_files_factor double NOT NULL default '0.1',
    steps mediumint(8) default '1',
    rows int(12) NOT NULL default '600',
    timespan int(12) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

I couldn't understand what is wrong in the syntax.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Probably need to pass integers/decimals and not strings to those types (int, double). Remove the single quotes from your 600.

Comment: remove fields until you find which one cause you the problem

Comment: I found it: rows is a reserved word in MariaDB https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/reserved-words/ use a different column name (numrows or something)

Comment: Thanks JacobH ! Changed the column name. Problem solved.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - 1064 almost always point exactly at, or immediately, after the offending token.  No need to fish around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this solution is that the scripts all fail. The SQLs are looking for the Table Column 'rows'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes around the default values on number fields and rename column rows.  rows is a reserved word.

```
CREATE TABLE rra (
    id mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    hash varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
    name varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
    x_files_factor double NOT NULL default 0.1,
    steps mediumint(8) default 1,
    rra_rows int(12) NOT NULL default 600,  -- rows is a reserved word
    timespan int(12) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```